# How does the computer know how to display text and GUI on the screen?

Tags: boot, display, bios

This might be a stupid and weird question but I really can't sleep until I find the answer. How does the computer know how to display text and GUI on the screen? 
If I'm not mistaken the boot process of a x86 computers goes like this:

- BIOS starts the CPU and the rest of the hardware and it checks if everything is working
- the CPU executes the code from the first 512? bytes of the boot partition and the screen displays the bootloader menu
- the selected kernel is executed
- etc.

My question is: If there's no operating system before the kernel is started, how does the computer know how to display the text on the screen? BIOS and the bootloader can display some text and a basic GUI. How do they do this? Does the BIOS/bootloader tell the CPU(GPU?) that it has to display a blue pixel on let's say position (0,0), then a white pixel on (1,0) etc?

My second theory is that the BIOS has a basic display's driver that has some sort of API to print on the screen. Is there some kind of print() function available from the display's drivers?

From what I have seen the assembly functions to print text are specific to each operating system so it can't be something available directly through the CPU's instruction set.

Part 2 of my question is, how do desktop environments like KDE or GNOME work? Let's say I want to create a completely new desktop environment for linux. Where do I start? There's no functions in C/C++ or any other high level language to display a *n color* prixel on position (x,y). What language is the program that displays the dekstop written in? Does it create the desktop pixel by pixel? 
How do libraries like GTK or Qt work? I know that I can display a window with only a few functions but how do those functions really work?

Sorry if my questions aren't clear. English is not my first language.

Comment: I don't know but maybe there's a fairly direct link between the screen and the memory it reads from, and no need for a GPU there. if you open a windows cmd prompt and you type `C:\>debug<ENTER>` `-f b800:0 FA0 21 CE' (fill from that address, FA0 i.e. 4000 bytes) then the prompt fills up with some chars.  It may be a bit like that. Like data written to memory and the screen gets it But i'm guessing wildly. That would've worked in DOS I think too.

Comment: Also you ask a GREAT question but they might not like it on this site. As they may say it's not about hardware or software.. you could try arstechnica forum

Comment: the BIOS chip on the motherboard contains enough intelligence to display this text and the graphics adapter is capable of text only modes in hardware that do not require a driver or software interaction. see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_10H and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VGA-compatible_text_mode and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VESA_BIOS_Extensions

Comment: @FrankThomas can a program wack the screen into text mode temporarily and display stuff the way the bios does, then go back to normal?

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, yes, thats what VESA tries to do with VTTYs under linux, but it is unreliable.

Comment: The OS Linux windows even bios all have code to handle wetting text to the display. As for the downvote I find this question extremely broad.

Comment: @Ramhound You wrote "The OS Linux windows even bios all have code to handle wetting text to the display" <-- Nobody was doubting that Windows or Linux or the BIOS, have code for GETTING text to the display. The questioner clearly knows that.

Comment: Sorry if this kind of questions is not supported here. Actually thanks to your comments I managed to find the answers by myself :) THX.

Comment: The PC display is a subsystem that is either in text mode or in graphics mode.  In text mode, the display subsystem accepts ASCII code, and then uses font bitmaps to generate the pixels.  In graphics mode the framebuffer memory stores the values of the red, green and blue values for each addressable pixel.  A GPU is for calculation of pixel values, e.g. for shapes, shading and motion, or codec processing.

Comment: @M0rning You could try posting your answer.. if you're lucky then any further errors in your understanding could get corrected. Or if your understanding is right, then you may get some confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, there's a ROM (read only memory) chip on the motherboard that tells it how to display whatever GUI it needs to. You think of it as having no software, but it does, it comes preinstalled from the manufacturer. Actually, you'd more likely call this "firmware" since it's software that's hard wired to the chip.

As for graphical desktop environments, there's really nothing special about them. They draw to the screen the same way as every other program does. All you really need to draw to a screen is to know the address of whatever chip you have that is in charge of processing graphics (usually a GPU or IGPU/APU). When normal programs do this I believe they request this information from the operating system, so if you were to write your own graphical desktop environment you would have to figure out what address to send your data to. The address you need should be provided by the drivers for whatever G/IG/APU you have.

Answer (score 0):

In two major parts:

1. After MBR is loaded its code loads a second stage of boot code called Windows Boot Manager or GRUB on Linux. This boot manager/loader has text and graphics functions implemented in code or uses direct BIOS access for text output.
2. After loading the OS (Windows, Linux, etc.) using any programming language like C, C++, Java, Basic you have access to functions implemented in kernel and/or libraries which allow writing or drawing on screen. Every programming language today has some IDE (integrated development environment) which greatly simplifies writing of user code.